# What's the best way to return 2 results from a method

Tags: objective-c, ios, pass-by-reference

I have a method that returns an integer and I now also want to return a small struct or class. If I was using C++ I would pass a reference to the struct in as a parameter. In iOS using ARC, I think the equivalent is to use a pointer to a pointer that has the __autoreleasing attribute which I find a bit cumbersome.

I could return an array containing the two values but then think I would be alloc'ing more than necessary and I could be using this a lot (100,000 calls).

Comment: You could just use objc++ and pass a struct by reference, like you would in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even with ARC, you can just pass in a struct by reference or an object pointer...

Pass the struct by ref just like you would in C++, e.g. `&aStruct`

```
-(int)getStuffOut:(SomeStruct *)aStruct {
   if(!aStruct) {
      return 0;
   }
   aStruct->myInt = 12345;
   aStruct->myFloat = 12.345f;
   return 1;
}
```

Or:

```
-(int)getStuffOut:(SomeClass *)anObject {
   if(!anObject) {
      return 0;
   }
   anObject.myIntProperty = 12345;
   anObject.myFloatProperty = 12.345f;
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you check `aStruct` for nil!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Yeah, I forget that error checking isn't already ingrained into everyone. =) Edited to include for the sake of correctness!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ARC you dont have to worry about memory management if you're using plain Objective-C.

Custom objects are passed by reference, so you can pass your OBJ-C object to your method and fill your stuff in.

Or you can return a Struct that holds the two values

```
+(struct YourStruct)someMethod:(NSString *)someParam;

+(YourStruct)someMethod:(NSString)someParam {

    //some method code

    YourStruct st;

    //Do something here with the struct

    return st;
}
```

Comment: I can't do that because the return value is used for the integer. Also I think this will make a new instance of YourStruct won't it?

Comment: Add that return value to your struct, then your struct will contain the return value an the extra data you're trying to send

Comment: No they are separate variables. The struct is used by many methods so I would have to add all of the original return types. That can't be right.

Comment: @Ant, you can make a new structure type that encapsulates both the original structure and your return type of choice.  That said, I think you just want to do it the normal C way, which is by passing pointers that you can "fill in".

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are advised against putting objects into structs with Objective-C as it won't know what memory management to do with it.

Comment: @CarlNorum yes, I would ideally like to do it the normal C way but I don't understand the ARC syntax to do that and everything I have read _seems_ to imply that it isn't right. I would like to _go with the flow_ and do it the Objective C way.

Comment: @Paul.s yes, that is my impression too.

Comment: What's the issue with the pointer to a pointer method? You shouldn't have too many of these api's or it might be a smell that your api's need some rethinking.

Comment: @Ant Can you pass an Objective-C object to your method to fill in?, as far as I know custom objects are passed by reference, so you can fill stuff in in your method. And if you're using arc, you don't have to worry about memory management, just create it and pass it.

Comment: @Ecarrion That's it. It's so simple I missed it. Could you post that as an answer and I'll accept it?